# Why did changing my name cause me to lag on multiplayer servers?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yesterday I changed my name in Minecraft. When I went back on I was experiencing serious lag that I haven't had before. Such as when I log into my favorite server Mineplex I lag for minutes and every 5 or so minutes I have major lag spikes.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I don't believe name changes cause lag- there's no reason they could. Is there anything else that might be affecting connection quality?

Answer (score 2):

Name changes won't cause lag. If anything, the server is running slow or it's not your computer's best day.

Answer (score -1):

Mineplex is naturally laggy without Optifine, changing your name didn't make a difference. Try installing Optifine from [here](http://optifine.net) and get the latest version. Mess around with your video settings making sure everything is on "fastest." This should help lots.